# Force return all fields including overridden ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am running a `select` query using `mongoose`. In the schema of the model, it is set to exclude two fields, e.g.:

```
contents: {
    type: String
    select: false
},
password: {
    type: String
    select: false
}
```

However, when I want to include those fields in exactly one find query, e.g.:

```
App.findById(_appId)
    .exec(err, result){ ... }
```

without adding a `.select` statement listing every single field in the model. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I had read [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) more carefully :P. This is possible by adding the following `select` query to the previous query:

```
.select('+contents +password');
```

It still fetched the rest of the model :D

Answer (score 0):

If you've specified select:false on fields, there's no way around having to explicitly  override this behavior in your query:

```
.select('contents password')...
```

If you don't want this behavior remove the select:false.  If you want to retain the bahavior, but find yourself making that query repeatedlly, consider a static method on your model.

```
schema.statics.materialize = function (appId, cb) {

    return this.findById(appId).select('contents password').
        exec(cb);
};
```